# How to know abnormal disconnection(TCP) between client and AWS ELB in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcp, amazon-elb

Let's say this situation,

1. I use TCP protocol for both **front-end(client<->ELB)** and **back-end(ELB<->EC2)** connections.
2. Normaly, the ELB forwards the request to the EC2.
3. So, if client sends a disconnection request, it will be processed with no problem.

but, if there is an **abnormal way** like something wrong in the Ethernet cable or cut off, in the client, can EC2 knows this situation through ELB?

also, is there any other solution?

Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELB has the facility for idle-timeout. You can set this to reasonable value. ELB can detect that client is not responsive thus and close the connection towards EC2 instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/